# C++ version for PHP-Snoopy

Tags: php, c++, snoopy

are there any C++ version for PHP Snoopy?
Snoopy is a PHP class that provides the functionality of a web-browser.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest pure C++ solution I know is people that have written there own browser automation or scraping using Qt and Webkit, though there doesn't seem to be a library you could interface directly with. Most of the code snippets that are posted using the Python binding to Qt and Webkit.

You could try using [phantomjs](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) directly as opposed to through its Javascript API.